# PyQt combobox selective text formatting

Tags: python, pyqt, qcombobox, text-formatting

Merry Christmas guys!

I am new to PyQt4 programming and using  Qt Designer for most of UI development. However I have a specific requirement to populate a QComboBox through Python code. More so I want to change text formatting (Bold, Red Background color) for some of the entries.

Essentially the combobox entries should appear as follows:

John

Tom

Henry

**Michelle**

Ashish

Jo-Huang

....

In terms of code I want to do something like this:

```
nameList = ('John','Tom','Henry','Michelle','Ashish','Jo-Huang', ...)
colorNameList = ('Michelle','Jennifer','Claudia','JimSung', ...)
callBackObj.NameComboBox.clear()
callBackObj.NameComboBox.addItem(QString('Account Names'))
for name in nameList:
    if name in colorNameList:
       callBackObj.NameComboBox.addItem(name) #Make this entry bold and red background
    else:
       callBackObj.NameComboBox.addItem(name)
```

The following code failed:

```
nameList = ('John','Tom','Henry','Michelle','Ashish','Jo-Huang', ...)
colorNameList = ('Michelle','Jennifer','Claudia','JimSung', ...)
callBackObj.NameComboBox.clear()
callBackObj.NameComboBox.addItem(QString('Account Names'))
for name in nameList:
    item = PyQt4.QtGui.QStandardItem(str(account))
    if name in colorNameList:
       item.setBackground(PyQt4.QtGui.QColor('red'))
    callBackObj.NameComboBox.addItem(item)
```

Error msg:

TypeError: arguments did not match any overloaded call:

  QComboBox.addItem(QString, QVariant userData=QVariant()): argument 1 has unexpected type 'QStandardItem'

  QComboBox.addItem(QIcon, QString, QVariant userData=QVariant()): argument 1 has unexpected type 'QStandardItem'

The following code worked :):

```
nameList = ('John','Tom','Henry','Michelle','Ashish','Jo-Huang', ...)
colorNameList = ('Michelle','Jennifer','Claudia','JimSung', ...)
callBackObj.NameComboBox.clear()
callBackObj.NameComboBox.addItem(QString('Account Names'))
model = callBackObj.NameComboBox.model()
for name in nameList:
    item = PyQt4.QtGui.QStandardItem(str(account))
    if name in colorNameList:
       item.setBackground(PyQt4.QtGui.QColor('red'))
    model.appedRow(item)
```

Many Thanks

Rahul

Comment: Thanks Reticality for your response. However that doesn't work. Getting following error: <br>TypeError: arguments did not match any overloaded call:
  QComboBox.addItem(QString, QVariant userData=QVariant()): argument 1 has unexpected type 'QStandardItem'
  QComboBox.addItem(QIcon, QString, QVariant userData=QVariant()): argument 1 has unexpected type 'QStandardItem'

Comment: What exactly is your question? You have code that works. The error with the code that doesn't work is because the method `QComboBox.addItem()` is not expecting to be passed an instance of `QStandardItem` (as the error message clearly states). `QStandardItem`s should be appended/inserted into the model for the combobox (which is what you do in the code that works). Am I missing something?

Comment: @Rahul, you probably meant to notify that you found the solution, but posted that in your own question. If you found out a solution, please post it as an *answer* here.

Answer (score 0):

The following code worked :):

```
nameList = ('John','Tom','Henry','Michelle','Ashish','Jo-Huang', ...)
colorNameList = ('Michelle','Jennifer','Claudia','JimSung', ...)
callBackObj.NameComboBox.clear()
callBackObj.NameComboBox.addItem(QString('Account Names'))
model = callBackObj.NameComboBox.model()
for name in nameList:
     item = PyQt4.QtGui.QStandardItem(str(account))
     if name in colorNameList:
        item.setBackground(PyQt4.QtGui.QColor('red'))
     model.appedRow(item)
```

Cheers

Rahul